# python pip install returns SSL error

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ssl-certificate

Recently I've started working at a large company. I've installed python and am now trying to install packages (using pip, which is installed) but get the following error (numpy is an example, but this error occurs for every package):

```
> pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

Because I have the idea that I get the error because I'm in a corporate network I tried the following (because someone else on StackOverflow did so as well):

```
> pip -vvv install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  1 location(s) to search for versions of numpy:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.python.org
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for numpy
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 294, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 461, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 250, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 571, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for numpy
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
There was an error checking the latest version of pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\outdated.py", line 126, in pip_version_check
    headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 373, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong and how I can fix this? My work laptop runs windows 10.

I would be very grateful if somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. The company uses a proxy, if this is temporarily turned off I can install packages without a problem.

I hope this helps others in the same situation